# how can i install SVN(subversion) and integrate with httpd (apache) in centos6

Tags: http, svn, centos

I am using CentOS release 6.4 (final) which has httpd (Apache) installed by default. Recently I installed Subversion using `#yum install subversion` and now I need to integrate SVN with Apache. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Better ask inside [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Collabnet Subversion Edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion). From that page:

> Free fully-automated installer/updater for software stacks of Subversion, Apache, and ViewVC fronted by a powerful web console for administration and server health check monitoring.